# Is unique_lock::unlock underspecified in the C++11 standard?

Tags: c++, c++11

The C++11 standard defines `unique_lock::unlock` as (§ 30.4.2.2.2, p. 1159)

```
void unlock();
Effects: pm->unlock()
Postcondition: owns == false
Throws: system_error when an exception is required (30.2.2).
Error conditions:
  — operation_not_permitted — if on entry owns is false.
```

All other locking operations specify that an exception is thrown on at least two occasions:

- The mutex is NULL (throws `system_error` with `errc::operation_not_permitted`)
- The mutex is already locked (throws `system_error` with `errc::operation_not_permitted`)

The problem with invalid mutex is obviously possible for `unlock` also, however, the standard specifies the behaviour of the program only for the locking problems. Is it a real error in the standard or am I missing something?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. Why is it "obviously possible" for `unlock` to be called when the mutex is invalid? You can infer that as the effect of `unlock()` is `pm->unlock()`, that to avoid undefined behavior `pm` must not be null and the contract for the `BasicLockable` `*pm` must be met, so the lock must be owned by the current execution agent. Is there some subtlety that I'm missing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Although not explicitly stated, `unique_lock` has the following invariants:

```
if pm == nullptr then owns == false
if owns == true then pm != nullptr
```

There is just no way to get the `unique_lock` into a state that violates these invariants except via undefined behavior.  So the clause:

```
— operation_not_permitted — if on entry owns is false.
```

covers the case that `pm == nullptr`.

Note that `~unique_lock()` only calls `pm->unlock()` if `owns` is true.  If `owns` is true, then `pm != nullptr` and thus `unlock()` can't throw.

Answer (score 0):

`pm` is the `mutex_type` and the definition for unlock in `std::mutex` is:

```
void unlock() noexcept;
```

That is, the `unlock` function cannot throw any exceptions, therefore `unique_lock::unlock` doesn't have to inherit any of those exceptions. As to why it can throw any exception at all is a mystery.

It is kind of bothersome that the destructor for `unique_lock` may throw an exception (since I guess it may have to call `unlock` where it can also).  This seems bad to me, since using a lock object to properly unlock during exception handling is a very common idiom.  It's really bad that the lock can throw an exception during stack unwinding -- especially since the underlying mutex isn't allowed to.

Something is definitely wrong here.

*I'm still working from the last public draft, perhaps this was fixed*

Comment: The am looking at the actual C++11 standard. Neither `unique_ptr::~unique_ptr` is `noexcept`, nor the proposal to implicitly add noexcept for destructors has been implemented, so it hasn't been fixed.  However, I think this is a different problem. The standard does not specify what happens in the case, when `unique_ptr` has no associated mutex and `unlock` is called on that lock.